# ODE - Determining a conservative system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to show that $$2y^2-2x^2+x^4$$ is conserved along all orbits.

I know that I need to find a function E = E(x, y) such that

$$ \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{x}}\cdot x^{'} +  \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{y}}\cdot y^{'} =  \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{x}}\cdot f+  \frac{\partial{E}}{\partial{y}}\cdot g = 0 $$

Can I say that $E(x,y)=2y^2-2x^2+x^4$ and how do I choose $x^{'}$ and $y^{'}$?

I tried solving and I got $x^{'}=y$ and  $y^{'}=x-x^3$. Is this right?

Comment: This problem description seems incomplete.

Comment: I am also thinking the same thing.

Comment: Good!  For example, I would assume a question about ODEs would have an ODE somewhere.

Comment: If we are allowed to define our own system of ODEs, I vote for the following:  $x'(t)=0, y'(t)=0$.

Comment: @Michael Too trivial :-P

Answer (score 1):

Take $H=\frac14(2y^2-2x^2+x^4)$ as Hamiltonian and consider the system
$$
x'=\frac{\partial H}{\partial y},\qquad y'=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}
$$